# What does conversion to non-scalar error means? How can I resolve it?

Tags: c++

So I wanted to create a class that deals with a student, who has a name, and a defined maximum number of subjects, for which he can have a limited number of marks (expressed by floats 1-10).
The code has Italian words as variables and comments, but I think it's pretty understandable what I tried to do. **The struct** is set to be of an array of 15 elements, each one containing a name, an array of marks and a counter.
**The constructor** sets the names of the subjects and sets all the marks of each subject to 0 (and I'll explain why).
**Methods:** getMaterie prints all the subjects; setVoto sets a mark in a certain subject and increase the counter; getVoti prints all the marks of a subject; getMedia makes an average of your marks and return the value(for this I used a counter, or it would be /30 and it is not correct).

**My error is on line 66: conversion from 'Studente*' to non-scalar type 'Studente' requested**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct mat{
    string nome;
    float voti[30];
    int counter;
}m[15];

class Studente{
    private:
        string nome;
        string materia[];
    public: Studente(string nom, int nm, string nomemateria[]){     //costruttore: richiesti nome dello studente, nome delle materie e l'indice per indicare
        nome = nom;                                                 //la quantità delle materie
        for(int i=0; i<nm; i++){        //ciclo con cui si impostano i nomi delle materie
            m[i].nome = nomemateria[i];     
            for(int j=0; j<30; j++){        //ciclo con cui si impostano a ZERO tutti gli elementi degli array dei voti (per la media!)
                m[i].voti[j]=0;
            }
        }
    }

    public: void getMaterie(int nm){            //si richiede il numero di materie totali. E' necessario perchè l'utente può decidere (su un massimo di 15)
        for(int i=0; i<nm; i++){
            cout<<i<<" "<<m[i].nome;
        }
    }

    public: void setVoto(int nm, float voto){       //si richiede il numero di materia alla quale inserire il voto, e il voto da inserire
        m[nm].voti[m[nm].counter] = voto;
        m[nm].counter++;
    }

    public: void getVoti(int nm){           //si richiede il numero di riferimento della materia della quale si vogliono stampare i voti
        for(int i=0; i<nm; i++){
            cout<<m[i].voti[i]<<" ";
        }
    }

    public: float getMedia(int nm){     //si richiede l'indice della materia di cui si vuole fare la media dei voti
        float media=0;
        for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
            media+= m[nm].voti[i];
        }
        return (media/m[nm].counter);
    }
};

int main(){
    string nome;
    int quantematerie;

    cout<<"Inserisci nome studente: "; cin>>nome;
    cout<<"Inserisci numero delle materie: "; cin>>quantematerie;

    string nomimaterie[quantematerie];

    for(int i=0; i<quantematerie; i++){
        string risposta;
        cout<<"Inserisci nome materia "<<i+1<<": "; cin>>risposta;
        nomimaterie[i] = risposta;
    }

    Studente s = new Studente(nome, quantematerie, nomimaterie);

    int scelta = 0;

    while(1){
    cout<<"1. Stampa tutte le materie 2.Imposta voto in materia x 3.Guarda voti materia x 4.Media materia x 0. Esci"<<endl<<"Scelta: "; cin>>scelta;
    switch(scelta){
        case 1: s.getMaterie(quantematerie);
        case 2: int materia; float voto; cout<<"Inserici numero materia a cui aggiungere voto: "; cin>>materia;
        cout<<"Inserisci voto da inserire: "; cin>>voto; s.setVoto(materia, voto); break;
        case 3: cout<<"Inserisci numero materia: "; cin>>materia; s.getVoti(materia); break;
        case 4: cout<<"Inserisci numero materia: "; cin>>materia; s.getMedia(materia); break;
        case 0: return 0;
        default: cout<<"Valore non riconosciuto";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "expressed by floats 1-10" - why are you using floats for that? That looks like a job for integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new` gives you a pointer to the newly allocated memory.  The error is telling you that you can't assign a `Studente*` to a `Studente`, i.e. you need to use:

```
Studente* s = new Studente(...)
```

Or better yet, just allocate the object on the stack since you don't need heap memory in this case:

```
Studente s{nome, quantematerie, nomimaterie};
```

Or if you insist on using the heap, use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) for better semantics, automatic cleanup, etc.